# How to access to each server by using vHost Nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, ip, host, vhosts

I use vhost in nodejs to create multiple host like this

```
var connect = require('connect')
var vhost = require('vhost')
var express = require('express')


var app = express()


app.use(vhost('a', function (req, res) {
  console.log("Y");
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
  res.end('hello from a!')
}))


app.use(vhost('b', function (req, res) {
  console.log("G");
  res.end('hello from b!')
}))

app.listen(8080)
```

and add

```
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX(my ip) a
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX(my ip) b
```

to ect/host file

My question is when i use my machine to access,

```
http://a:8080
http://b:8080
```

it is success. But when i use my iPad to access it i can not access both of them.

How can i access each of host in my iPad?